# Why is the cyclotomic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

As defined in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) (and this is the same definition I was given in class), it is not clear to me why the cyclotomic polynomial is over $\mathbb{Q}$.

It is over $\mathbb{C}$, but I don't see a reason for the coefficient to be in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Can anyone help with this one?

Comment: It follows from for example the Möbius inversion formula on that Wikipedia page.

Comment: Coefficients are in fact in $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen But the Moebius inversion formula instructs to divide polynomials. This explains why it is in $\mathbb{Q}$. But why are coefficients integer ?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - I did not study complex analysis yet

Comment: @Sasha - this is proved in my notebook based on the assumption that this polynimial is over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @Belgi, that application of the Möbius function does not involve complex analysis at all.

Comment: @Sasha, when you divide two **monic** polynomials with integer coefficients, the result will also have integer coefficients. Think about what happens when you do long division.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, I am convinced now :) Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - But I do not undertand why they are in $\mathbb{Q}$!

Comment: Ah, I misread Sasha's comment as being from you, @Belgi. Sorry.  I'll delete my comment.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130175/cyclotomic-polynomials-in-kx-are-defined-over-the-prime-subfield-of-k/130201#130201

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from the following formula and induction on n.

$\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d(X) = X^n - 1$

**Edit**
Let $g(X) = \prod_{d\mid n, d ＜ n}\Phi_d(X)$.
By the induction hypothesis $g(X) ∈ \mathbb{Q}[X]$.
Hence $\Phi_n(X) = (X^n - 1)/g(X) ∈ \mathbb{Q}[X]$

Comment: How does it follow ?

Comment: @Belgi Then you use Jyrki's comment on division of monic polynomials with integer coefficients (and induction)